# Removing Client Response Url parameter

Tags: jsp, url, servlets, filter

**Question.** When having an client URL with following parameters `contactVia=email&interestedIn=petRock&terms=on` how can one remove the (present) attribute `terms=on` when the call reaches the servlet?

So the response URL becomes `contactVia=email&interestedIn=petRock`

**Context.** Values in textboxes from the calling form are automatically added to the response URL, i have tried to remove terms by `request.removeAttribute();` and editing `request.getParameterMap();`.

But removeAttribute has no effect and the map is immutable. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Why the -1? I have looked through stackoverflow previous posts and have not been able to find a working solution. Their are no (that i know off) methods attached to the request or response object that you can use directly to remove the attribute from the URL, so i think the question is valid. I know you can do this with JS before you send the request but that is not what i want to do in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of scenario is one of the reasons that [javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html) exists. You can subclass it and override its behaviour.

A [javax.servlet.Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) is a good place to do this:

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/same/as/your/servlet")
public class ParameterFilter implements Filter {

    /*
     * Treat this as a guide only - it's not tested in any way
     */
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            final HttpServletRequestWrapper wrappedRequest = new HttpServletRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest)
                    request) {

                @Override
                public Map<String, String[]> getParameterMap() {
                    return request.getParameterMap()
                            .entrySet()
                            .stream()
                            .filter(mapEntry -> !mapEntry.getKey().equals("terms"))
                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(mapEntry -> mapEntry.getKey(), mapEntry -> mapEntry.getValue()));
                }

                @Override
                public Enumeration<String> getParameterNames() {
                    return new Vector(request.getParameterMap()
                            .keySet()
                            .stream()
                            .filter(key -> !key.equals("terms"))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList())).elements();
                }

                @Override
                public String getParameter(String name) {
                    return name.equals("terms") ? null : super.getParameter(name);
                }

                @Override
                public String[] getParameterValues(String name) {
                    return name.equals("terms") ? null : super.getParameterValues(name);
                }

                @Override
                public String getQueryString() {
                    final String[] queryTuples = super.getQueryString().split("&");
                    return String.join("&",
                                        Arrays.stream(queryTuples)
                                            .filter(pv -> !pv.matches("terms=?"))
                                            .collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new String[queryTuples.length]));
                }
            };

            chain.doFilter(wrappedRequest, response);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

You can make this more or less elaborate depending upon your needs.